# QML How to dynamically access ListView items

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I have a ListView which has dynamically added Items, and what I kinda want to know is how I could access items for example by index. Specifically, I want to have the color of the item rectangle change when I change the color using the Color Dialog. I guessed it should be maybe possible to first set a variable to the current item before calling the color dialog and then in the onAccepted method change the color of that item using the variable, but I don't know how to achieve anything of this in QML, because I am rather new to QML. Maybe you can offer even a cleaner way to change the color of the item's rectangle when the color dialog was closed (onAccepted). Thx for any help! :)

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Rectangle {
    id: listViewContainer
    width: parent.width/10*9;
    height: 50
    Behavior on height {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 100;
        }
    }

    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop {position: 0.0; color: "white" }
        GradientStop {position: 1.0; color: "silver" }
    }
    radius: 5
    ColorDialog {
        id: colorDialog
        title: "Please choose a color"
        onAccepted: {
            console.log("You chose: " + colorDialog.color)
            Qt.quit()
        }
        onRejected: {
            console.log("Canceled")
            Qt.quit()
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: playerDelegate
        Item {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: 50
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Row {
                    MouseArea {
                        width: 20
                        height: 20
                        onClicked: {
                            colorDialog.visible = true;
                            playerColor = colorDialog.color;
                            //open color dialog
                        }

                        Rectangle {
                            radius: 3
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            color: playerColor
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: playerListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model:
            ListModel {
                id: playerListViewModel;
                ListElement {
                    name: "Bill Smith"
                    playerColor: "red"
                }
        }
        delegate: playerDelegate
    }
    Button {
        id: addPlayerButton
        anchors.top: playerListView.bottom
        anchors.left: playerListView.left
        anchors.right: playerListView.right
        style: ButtonStyle {
            label: Text {
                text: "Add new player"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.Center
            }
        }
        onClicked: {
            root.addnewPlayer(playerListView); //dont worry about this method
            playerListViewModel.append({name: "Billy", playerColor: "blue"});
            listViewContainer.height += 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I run your example: `file:///tmp/untitled3/main.qml:9: TypeError: Cannot read property of null` Please post a complete, minimal example. I'm guessing this code was taken out of a larger piece of code, and hence the parent it's referring to is the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sure fire way to make a working colorDialog --

#### in playerDelegate

```js
 Component {
   id: playerDelegate
   Item {
     anchors.left: parent.left
     anchors.right: parent.right
     height: 50
     Column {
       Text {
         text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name
       }

      /* Object to store value from color selector */
       Item {
         id: colorSelector


           property color color: "#000000"
           onColorChanged: { playerColor = color; }

       }
/* box to display color */
       Rectangle {

         //Layout.fillWidth: true
         height: 120
         width: 120
         anchors.left: button.right
           //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
         color: colorSelector.color
         border.width: 1
         border.color: "#000000"

       }
/* button to open dialog -- can be mousearea or other clickable object */

       Button {
         id: button
         text: "Browse..."
         onClicked: {
           colorDialog.color = colorSelector.color
           colorDialog.open()
         }
       }

/* actual color dialog for this delegate */




       ColorDialog {
         id: colorDialog
         modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
         title: "Please choose a color"
         onAccepted: colorSelector.color = currentColor
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much, you are an angel! :D however, it is not completely working, whenever I choose a color, it does not change the rectangles color, but instead it generates this error message: qml: You chose: #fdfdfd
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver Any idea on how to fix this? Also you have to add newDialog.visible = true after the connect to show the dialog

Comment: Ok, now the color dialog itself works fine, however when I choose a color, it doesn't change it in the rectangle. Do i have to invoke any method to tell Qt that the rectangle's color is dirty?

Comment: I added while Debugging these lines:     console.log(newColor);
                playerListViewModel.get(index).playerColor = newColor;
                console.log(playerListViewModel.get(index).playerColor); Now I don't understand anything anymore: In the console it says: qml: #193ca2
qml: red So it just ignores the line setting the color?

Comment: I tried both and it did not work. The problem seems not to be in the ColorDialog, but in the function changeColor(). As I said I added these lines to the function: `function changeColor(newColor) {
                console.log(newColor);
                playerListViewModel.get(index).playerColor = newColor;
                console.log(playerListViewModel.get(index).playerColor);`, the first log reports that the function got the correct color. Then we set playerColor and report playerColor afterwards, but playerColor is red although we set it to something else the line before

Comment: Here is a full console.log: `qml: You chose: #2c07b3
qml: newColor=#2c07b3
qml: After setting playerColor = newColor, playerColor=red` As you see the = operator does not seem to work anymore, because playerColor is still red although setting it to #2c07b3. This bug is really making me nervous now, how can QML just ignore the = operator?

Comment: I don't quite understand your second thought. (The first one alone did not change anything) When I try what I think you mean, it says: Component objects cannot declare new properties.

Comment: I think I found something that will work for you. I edited my answer to include it

Comment: Just happy to help